# Android "Toast" when crashed with some details of crashing

Tags: android

Instead of showing force close OR when force close occurs, how can I send out a Toast/ Notification with some details about crashing. I know, it's a  tall order but where should I start ? Do I need ACRA ?

Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how it crashes.  Why not just try to catch the exceptions and handle them properly, so you can exit in a controlled fashion and send out the data you want.

Comment: Right now, I can not send out the data so thinking of showing the user the crashing error in the form of toast or notification. OR create a log on device. Any suggations ? ant examples?

Comment: You can log it yourself, or put it in the Android log and there are programs that will email the logcat out.  If you create your own logfile then you can also have a button to email the latest log file, if needed.

Comment: Thanks James! Sounds like a good approch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to extend Application class and then, inside the onCreate method, do something like this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate ()
{
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new UncaughtExceptionHandler(){

                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread arg0, Throwable arg1) {
                    //mytoast here


                }

            }
    );
    super.onCreate();


}
```

Don't forget to specify in your manifest file that you're using this new class :

```
    <application android:icon=""  android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="your.class">
```

Comment: I have added this in my app.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ACRA is probably your better option, as it allows you to receive the details of the crash, as well as show the user a message. It also comes with a great integration guide, and allows you to log custom data as well.

http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Comment: Right now, I can not send out the data so thinking of showing the user the crashing error in the form of toast or notification. OR create a log on device. Any suggations ? ant examples?